# Question about finite extensions and splitting fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Apparently any finite extension of a field with characteristic 0 is of the form $F(a)$ for some algebraic $a$. But wouldn't this mean that any two zeros of a polynomial (e. g. over $\mathbb{Q}$) would be linearly dependent (since the splitting field is a finite extension)?

Comment: Why should it mean that?

Comment: Because the splitting field is of the form $F(a_1,...,a_n)$ where the $a_i$ are the zeros

Comment: But why would they be linearly dependent?

Comment: It only means the roots a *algebraically* dependent – which is not a scoop.

Comment: In any case, wouldn't the above imply that any splitting field over any polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ would be generated by a single element (i. e. $a$)?

Comment: Yes, but $a$ need not be one of the roots of the polynomial. See a proof of the primitive element theorem here: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/6310/primitive.pdf